# PHP script with curl returns 200 response

Tags: php, curl

In the bellow snipet you can see that i am trying to download some data from a website via their API in JSON format.

My problem is that when i try to get the data in json format (25 mb of text data) the php script send me a 200 response (which you can see below). But the weird part is that the script actualy finishes executing and the response is downloaded by my browser as a file.

The url if inputed into browser returns correct data, even via wget i can download the contents from this url.

Could it be that curl will pass through the respose from the server to my browser?

```
$ch = curl_init("https://example.com/api/json/view/view_name?authtoken=xxxyyyaaaa&raw=true");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
$data = curl_exec ($ch);
```

downloaded file "myscriptname.php" which contains:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>200 OK</title>
</head><body>
<h1>OK</h1>
<p>The server is temporarily unable to service your
request due to maintenance downtime or capacity
problems. Please try again later.</p>
</body></html>
```

Comment: have you tried to change user agent?

Comment: the server ignores user agents, the data IS downloaded, but before it's downloaded, my browser downloads the html response and thinks everything is done

Comment: Maybe you could fiddle with the `Accept` HTTP header and see if that changes anything.

Answer (score 1):

Well this is what the cURL optin CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER you are using actually is for: to return the transferred content to the user agent.

Comment: but if I understand correctly, when `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` is set to false curl will print out the received data. If set to true it will return the data as string. The problem is that i don't want to print out the data, just save it to a file

Comment: You are right, sorry, my mistake. I do remember fiddling with the same issue some 4 years ago. I got it to work, I just cannot remember what the cause was currently. Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

Your request was OK , but server returned the content as html page (may be their API is not working) so you are getting the maintenance page as reply.
looking at php.net

```
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER    TRUE 
to return the transfer as a string of the return value of curl_exec()
 instead of outputting it out directly.
```

when i used curl to

```
 <?php
$ch = curl_init("http://localhost/testjson.php");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
$data = curl_exec ($ch);
print_r($data);
?>
```

what i got after exec is

```
{"result":["google","stack","facebook"]}
```

(this is because i printed the result using print_r($data);)

testjson.php is

```
<?php 
$data   = array ('result'=>array('google','stack','facebook'));
header('content-type:application/json');
echo json_encode($data);

?>
```

Comment: looking at the response type it's set to `application\json` ... :/